# Is gravity a direct result of Lorentz Contraction?

Tags: special-relativity, gravity, mass, inertial-frames

I am not a physicist. Curious to know if Gravity is a direct result or manifestation of the Lorentz Contraction between particles within a denser field of matter?

Curious to know if anyone has tried to explain gravity as a result of relativistic effects, instead of gravity itself generating those effects?

Apologies in advance for this naive question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No.** Special relativity on its own doesn't imply general relativity. It's not enough to have some invariance principles; you need to "turn on" mass-energy gravitating by specifying how they gravitate, with e.g. [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein%E2%80%93Hilbert_action). Indeed, special relativity is compatible with [all manner of alternatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternatives_to_general_relativity), or just not having gravity at all.

Comment: Do Stress-Energy Tensors play a role in the Lorentz Contraction (LC)? If so, does LC occur in a gravitational field?